# What is the differnece between string(75) and text as field types in qgis? how is it going to affect when I try to join them?

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-joins

I have been trying to join a table(250320) with a layer (IND_admn1) in qgis and it worked once(with another table-230320), but second time onwards it has been showing an error such that the join layer has null values. The join field is of type **text** while the target layer of type **string**. The same could be joined once but not again..why is it so? I tried using field calculator to create a new field of type string to solve the problem but again no use. Tried joining two integer fields but one is integer while other is integer(64 bit). 
State/UT is of type string, so is Name of State/ UT.
Pls help!
[image]

Comment: Glad you find your way to GIS StackExchange. 
1) You use the 'Join attributes by value' tool from the toolbox which generates a new layer or file with joined attributes directly. You can also join layers/tables via their Properties > Joins > +. That will create a join kept in memory. It's less cumbersome then when trying to join layers/tables using the tool from the toolbox. When the join is successful, you can save the joined layer as a new file.
2) What's the error being showed? QGIS does not discriminate between text and string as far as I know; its just a string. 
3) Check the contents!

Comment: Check also that you don't have trailing/leading spaces in your string data